# Restoring a circuit to correct resistance

Tags: resistors

I had a functioning circuit that was as follows
120v ac voltage
18.7 ohms resistance
On a 20 amp line

The circuits resistance values have since been changed because, in essence, they've been separated now into two independent circuits but still need to operate at an impedance of 18.7ohms

One circuits resistance is now 3 ohms another is at 10. In order to correct these two circuits, I understand I need to wire a 15 ohm and 8 ohm resistor, respectively, in series( not worrying about the .7ohm due to +- tolerances ) into each circuit. Can someone just double check my thought process and possibly suggest two resistors that might do the trick?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem; what are the circuits you're trying to power?  Also, we're talking resistors a foot long that need forced air cooling.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question, [Restoring a circuit to correct reistance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570154/restoring-a-circuit-to-correct-reistance) which was closed and a reason given. The procedure on SE is that you fix the question. You DO NOT repost it.

Comment: Know that no self-respecting electrician wants to make his hands dirty by taking part an effort which can be whatever - maybe burning a house or killing someone. I do not have a slightest idea what and where you exactly are able to burn or kill but I'm not going to be a person who is accused in a court of law for guiding you. Get a qualified electrician and let him see your system if you shame too much to show it here. AND KEEP IT DISCONNECTED until a competent professional has fixed it. You are not one and no answer to your ohm adding question makes you one.

Comment: this looks like the question, that was posted elsewhere, about in-floor heating pad that was cut into sections contrary to manufacturer's warning